# Copy and Paste in Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome-Terminal

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, gnome-terminal

I have been facing a situation at my gnome terminal, I use Ctrl+Insert to copy text and Shift+Insert to paste text in a terminal. The issue is whenever I paste using the shift+Insert the line is executed directly, I want to be able to paste only, and the line to be executed upon pressing Enter and not automatically.

can someone help me about this, is there a settings I can edit or something?

Comment: Enable "bracketed paste mode" in your shell, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44507798.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue that I have experienced many times.

Actually it is not a bug in gnome terminal in fact the command is executed automatically only when you copy the whole line including the invisible return character(this is particularly common when you copy from webpages or PDF files)

At the moment the only ways that I found to avoid this issue are:

- be careful when selecting the text and select the whole text without selecting the whole line.
- copy the text from the webpage or PDF into gedit and afterward copy from gedit to the terminal

For the same reason when you copy a multiline code all the lines except the last will always be executed.

If someone know a better solution to this issue I would like to know too

Comment: Thank you Damiano that worked for me I copied only the text itself, so it looks like the invisible return characters are also being copied and translated into Enter key.

Comment: This is changed in Ubuntu 21.04: pasting any text now will not execute it during the paste

Answer (score 2):

Another way of achieving this is to add double ampersand `&&` between your commands (instead of those return characters) and also you can replace all of those returns with `&&` via `sed` or `awk`.

You can do this by a `sed` command like this :

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ \&\& /g' filename
```

This will replace all carriage-returns with `&&` for you.(You should replace the filename with the name of your own file).

Also it has nothing to do with `gnome-terminal` , actually `bash` is interpreting those commands.The same situation exist for example in `Konsole` terminal.

Edit : `Zsh` hasn't that problem and executes multiple lines only once you hit the `Enter` button . So another solution would be to install and use `Zsh` instead of `bash` which is the default shell in almost (if not all) linux distributions.

You can install it via

```
apt install zsh
```

and make it default with

```
chsh yourusername -s /usr/bin/zsh
```